# Compare signal strength with Software Defined Radio

Tags: rtl-sdr, hackrf

I want to compare field strength with an RTL-SDR dongle or HackRF One. With comparing I mean being correct relative to one another, like if I know field strength of one in mW/m^2 then I know the other. I am pretty sure this works for a fixed bandwidth ([How to Measure Signal Strength](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/12896/how-to-measure-signal-strength)).

My remaining question is: Can I compare field strength of 145Mhzish to 900Mhzish? I wouldn't mind an inaccuracy of factor 3.

Comment: Sorry to say, but even measuring the relative (not absolute) field intensities of radiated e-m waves requires the use of a receive antenna with known characteristics at each received frequency, including the effects of its operating environment.  Even for laboratory grade test equipment, these conditions are difficult to realize outside of a calibrated test range.  Unfortunately such measurements using the antenna of an SDR dongle will have a high, and unknown amount of error, but that may not matter, for some purposes.

Comment: This antenna can be adjusted in size: https://greatscottgadgets.com/ant500/
What if I lessen my accuracy need to factor 10?

Comment: There seem to be a lot of people doing it nonetheless;
https://www.rtl-sdr.com/measuring-power-line-noise-neighbourhood-rtl-sdr-driveby-system/

https://www.rtl-sdr.com/rtl-sdr-used-as-a-spectrum-analyzer/